# The SSL connection could not be established when using emulator

Tags: c#, android, ssl, https, request

Hi I have a visual studio project running ISS web app, and I also have open anothe rvisual studio c# android project running in emulator debug.
When I send request using HttpClient to my web app API is get the error:
'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'

I have added the code: **ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;** to 'MainActivity.cs' to try to bypass the certificate check already as i was previously getting the error:
"Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.'"

I can access the API via browser using same url the android app is using. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code:

```
PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(PhotoPath);

            byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(PhotoPath);
            var base64image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);



            // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
            var jn = JobNo.Text.ToString();
            var url = serverurl + "api/Data/uploadimage";


            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler());
            
                var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                
                form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length), "base64image", "hello1.jpg");
                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, form);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// PUT api/<DataController>/uploadimage
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("uploadimage/")]
    public void uploadimage(string base64image)
    {
        try
        {
            var stream = Request.BodyReader.AsStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.Body.Length];
            //stream.Write(buffer);
            
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How was the SSL cert for the IIS web App generated?

Comment: I added through windows IIS manager, self signed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the difference is that browser is less stringent on it's security check than the built in HttpClient, it probably also has it's own list of certificate authorities it trusts and the criteria for checking them (I seem to remember that old Android version had a hard coded list of trusted CA's where as newer versions come from an updatable package).

You should read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

So you need to generate your own Certificate Authority and then use that to sign your cert for the webserver, the Certificate Authority Cert needs to be then added in to the Android Config for it to trust your self signed cert.

Depending on your requirements it might be easier to use a cert signed by a Certificate Authority that Android already trusts like e.g. https://letsencrypt.org/ (though a cert from them might be a problem in very old Android versions I seem to remember)

This might be different to how use the generated cert for IIS as below are my notes on how to generate the required config on Linux for Apache/nginx webserver that I used for testing my App with a local webserver with self signed cert. (you should be able to do this on windows with the right tools)

1. Create CA private key and Cert
   Create a config file `CA.conf` as per:-

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = US
ST = Localzone     
L = localhost    
O = Certificate Authority Local Center
OU = Develop      
CN = develop.localhost.localdomain
emailAddress = root@localhost.localdomain
```

2. Run the command `openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout ca_key.pem -out ca_cert.pem -days 1825 -config CA.cnf`
3. Create webserver secret key and Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
   Create a config file `localhost.cnf` as per below, adjusting the "alt_names" list to include the IP/DNS addresses that the webserver will be accessed on.

```
[req]
   default_bits  = 2048
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
   req_extensions = req_ext
   x509_extensions = v3_req
   prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = US
stateOrProvinceName = Localzone
localityName = Localhost
organizationName = Certificate signed by my CA
commonName = localhost.localdomain

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 127.0.0.2
IP.3 = 127.0.0.3
IP.4 = 192.168.0.1
IP.5 = 192.168.0.2
IP.6 = 192.168.0.3
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = localhost.localdomain
DNS.3 = dev.local
```

4. Run the command `openssl req -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost_key.pem -out localhost.csr -config localhost.cnf`
5. Sign the Cert for 1 year -
   Run the command `openssl x509 -req -days 398 -in localhost.csr -CA ca_cert.pem -CAkey ca_key.pem -CAcreateserial -out localhost_cert.pem -extensions req_ext -extfile localhost.cnf`
6. Copy the `ca_cert.pem` to the raw resource directory of the App.
7. Configure the App to use the local CA cert when debugging the App.
   Add the line `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the `Application` entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file
   Create the `network_security_config.xml` file in the App's xml folder with the content:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<debug-overrides>
<trust-anchors>
<certificates src="@raw/ca_cert"/>
</trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Note this cert will only be used when the App is built as debuggable.

Note you can change the `network_security_config.xml` to allow this Certificate Authority cert to be more trusted.

8. Use the the `localhost_cert.pem` and `localhost_key.pem` in your webserver config.