# How to install a self signed CA certificate programmatically on Android

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, cacerts

I have no idea about how to install a CA certificate programmatically. I only know to do it from Settings->Security and PRivacy-> Other Security settings -> Install from device storage -> Ca certificate.

I select the certificate from device storage and it installs it.

However the requirement is to install them as a part of the application i.e programmatically replicate the above installation through an app.  User interaction for permission is okay. Please let me know the steps to follow.

Comment: It would help to know the context of what you are trying to achieve with it. If it is something global you may not have permission to do it programatically for security reasons, but if it is something on your application it may be possible.

Comment: if you are asking about loading a self-signed client cert to allow an android app to access a server, see if my answer from 9-ish years ago helps: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624663/ssl-client-authentication-with-certificate-in-android

I haven't looked to see if anything major has changed since then, tho....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The SSL connection could not be established when using emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665753/the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-when-using-emulator)

Comment: Please disregard the previous dupe, that's for C#, not Android.